# Drop the values of an array on first column after my range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

the below is a slimmed code of my original macro.
the current result is it drops the values of `arrFlags` on columns equal to count to `rng`.
**the expected result** is drop the values of `arrFlags` on the first column after `rng`.

```
Sub question()

   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long, lastC As Long
   Dim arr, arrFlags
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     lastC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastR, lastC))

    arr = rng.Value2
    ReDim arrFlags(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 1)

    With rng.Offset(0, lastC + 1)            'I need here the first column after rng
        .Value = arrFlags
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I can understand what you try doing... If I would say **dropping the first arr column value at the end of `rng`**?

Comment: @FaneDuru , I mean  dropping the first `arrFlags` column value at the end of `rng`

Comment: I still not understand what you mean. Is it any connection between `arr` and `arrFlags` in terms of parent ? I mean, is it `arrFlags` extracted from `arr`, as its first column, or `arrFlags` is loaded in a different way and you did not show that? As it is, it is empty... Then, do you want dropping its value in column A:A, or after the last existing column?

Comment: `arrFlags` is empty - there are no values - therefore you don't see "inserts". If it had values, they would be written to column `C` - as you offset by 2.

Comment: @Ike , as I said on the question (it is a slimmed code ) , `arrFlags ` is not empty , it is loaded in a different way and no need show that.

Comment: @FaneDuru ,  as I said on the question (it is a slimmed code ) , `arrFlags`  is not empty , it is loaded in a different way and no need show that

Comment: A 'slimmed code' may mean a lot of things... Please answer the other question: "Then, do you want dropping its value in column A:A, or after the last existing column?"

Comment: @FaneDuru , after the last existing column

Comment: As you `redim` without `preserve` `arrFlags` *is empty* even if it had data beforehand.

Comment: Also: you can only redim the second dimension ... Without knowing anything about `arrFlags` it is hard to post a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just one line of code, by `resize` the range and then `offset`.

```
rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, rng.Columns.Count).Value2 = arrFlags
```